# Moving up and down the DOM in Jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, find, closest

Ok, so I am having a major issue figuring this out....and getting nowhere fast.

Question: Given the below HTML structure; use JQuery closest and find to go from the childOfSecond element to the third element and change its background color to orange when the second element is clicked.

I have to use these two methods, so I have tried multiple angles here. I feel like I am close, but just can't get it to behave.

Thank you so much for any help!

```
<fieldset>
<br />
      <br />
      <div id="prob2">
        <div class="box first">
        </div>
        <div class="box second">
          <div class="child-of-second"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="box third">
        </div>
      </div>

      <script>
      $('#prob2 .box.second').on('click', function(){


        var childOfSecond = $("child-of-second").closest("div").find(".box.third").css("background", "orange");




    });
      </script>
      <br />
      <br />


  </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Several problems. First selector is looking for a tag `<child-of-second>` not a class.

It's closest `<div>` is `.box.second` which is a sibling of the one you want. However `find()` only looks for descendents not siblings

Try

```
$(".child-of-second").parent().next().css("background", "orange");
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!